# How to flatten multiple zipped RDDs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I've zipped three RDDs and as a result got a nested structure.

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List(3, 4, 5))
val rdd3 = sc.parallelize(List(6, 7, 8))

val finalRDD = rdd1.zip(rdd2).zip(rdd3)
```

The `finalRDD` looks like

```
((1,3),6)
((2,4),7)
((3,5),8)
```

How can I flatten the structure to the following?

```
(1,3,6)
(2,4,7)
(3,5,8)
```

Comment: Just **map** it. `val finalRDD = rdd1.zip(rdd2).zip(rdd3).map { case ((a, b), c) => (a, b, c) }`

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work

```
finalRDD.map(r => (r._1._1,r._1._2,r._2))
```